# Positioning a input box in canvas, the x and y get changed magically

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs

So my text box appears in the correct spot on the web version.

Once I download the scorm package and upload into a lms and launch the Text box appears in a new spot and looks bad. Its the same code both places.

How can I fix this?

```
var textBoxInput = document.createElement("input");
        textBoxInput.id = "textBoxInput";
        textBoxInput.type = "text";
        textBoxInput.style.width = "270px";
        textBoxInput.style.font = "14pt Arial";
        textBoxInput.style.padding = "10px";
        textBoxInput.style.height = "8px";

        self.stage.canvas.parentElement.insertBefore(textBoxInput, canvas);
        var textBoxInputControl = new createjs.DOMElement(textBoxInput);
        textBoxInputControl.x = 10;
        textBoxInputControl.y = bounds.height - 55;
```

Adjusting this position here.

```
 function setInputPosition() {
        if (views.questionContainer) {
            var bounds = views.questionContainer.getBounds();
            var difx = views.questionContainer.x - ((views.questionContainer.x + self.stage.canvas.parentElement.offsetLeft) * self.stage.canvas.clientWidth / 800)
            var dify = views.questionContainer.y - views.textBoxInputControl.oHeight - ((views.questionContainer.y) * self.stage.canvas.clientHeight / 600)


            views.textBoxInputControl.x = 0 - difx;
            views.textBoxInputControl.y = ((bounds.height) * self.stage.canvas.clientHeight / 600) - 80 - dify;
            views.textBoxInputControl.width = (bounds.width - 116) * canvas.clientHeight / 600
            //$("#textBoxInput").css('font-size', (16 * (self.stage.canvas.clientHeight / 600)) - 2);
            //var wtfHeight = (16 * (self.stage.canvas.clientHeight / 600) + 2);
            //$('#textBoxInput').height(wtfHeight);
            //$('#textBoxInput').innerHeight(wtfHeight);
            //views.textBoxInputControl.height = wtfHeight;
            //views.textBoxInputControl.oHeight = wtfHeight;
            //views.textBoxInputControl.setBounds(views.textBoxInputControl.x, views.textBoxInputControl.y, views.textBoxInputControl.width, views.textBoxInputControl.height);
            //views.textBoxInputControl.htmlElement.height = wtfHeight;

            views.textBoxInput.style.height = views.textBoxInputControl.height + "px";
            views.textBoxInput.style.width = views.textBoxInputControl.width + "px";
        }
    }
```

[image: Good web version]

[image: Bad once launched in new window as SCORM package from blackboard LMS]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element in dev tools to see if there are any unwanted css margins or padding being applied from somewhere?

Comment: yeah the numbers for a few things get changed. Im guessing its based on screen size. Not sure how to account for this.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint to the dom element in Chrome Dev Tools to find out what script is changing the values on you. That might help at least identify the script that is causing the problem. Also, which LMS are you using? You might check the settings to make sure it isn't doing anything unsual.